# How to select elements from an html string using jquery

Tags: jquery, string, parsing

I am using jquery to get the data from one web page and show it in another page. Basically, I have a string that includes the `html` code of the page such as:

```
var str = '<head><title>some title</title><head><body><div class="main"><div id="inner"></div></div></body>';
```

and I need to get the content of `"#inner"` from `str`. How to is this possible? I am looking for some solution that is fast, short and without using a lot of memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery allows you to build HTML from strings, so you can just find the element within:

```
var str = '<head><title>some title</title><head><body><div class="main"><div id="inner"></div></div></body>';
$(str).find('#inner');
```

This works as long as you're looking for DOM elements. This will not handle the `<head/>` of the document.

Answer (score 0):

You can build HTML Elements from strings..

```
var str = '<head><title>some title</title><head><body><div class="main"><div id="inner"></div></div></body>';
var a = $(str);
var _innerHTML = a.find("#inner").html();
```